# Unable to get JSON response from cURL

Tags: php, json, curl, oauth-2.0, instagram-api

When I am hitting the URL https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=&redirect_uri=http://localhost/Instagram_flow/result.php&response_type=code&scope=basic+comments+relationships+likes in browser I get the response as:

**{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "You must include a valid client_id, response_type, and redirect_uri parameters"}**

But when I do a cURL on this URL:

```
 $curl=curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=&redirect_uri=http://localhost/Instagram_flow/result.php&response_type=code&scope=basic+comments+relationships+likes');
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $data = curl_exec($curl);
 echo $data;
 curl_close($curl);
```

It returns nothing. I hit this URL in Postman too, there also it is giving a JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include a client_id in the request parameters...otherwise you're not authenticating anybody.

When you registered your application with instagram, you should have received credentials that you can send in your requests so that they can verify that it's your application accessing the API. Otherwise, any ol' person with an Internet could connect to the API and mess with everybody else's data.

I recommend reading through [this OAuth2 tutorial](https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified) to get a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: Yeah, that I understand. But when I pass invalid client ID (say any string) , then also it gives an error in JSON. I just want to do a health check on that URL so that a more appropriate and formatted message can be displayed to the user instead of plain JSON. Thats y i did a cURL before allowing a user to click on the link.

Comment: It's a standard OAuth authentication error message. You'll see an error message all the time until you successfully authenticate. If you're adding in an invalid client_id then the error message should be different (but you'll still get one). I'm not sure what a "health check" is -- the point of curling that URL is to get an access token to access the API. If you just send garbage in the query parameters then it'll keep telling you that you're not authenticating...

Comment: For access token, yes we do curl the url. I thought if it is possible to catch that JSON response. Why it isn't returning in curl? While in case of access token too, JSON response is returned and we can have it by curl. Why this url is not returning in same way? Is there anything related to curl which I am missing?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean by "I thought if it is possible to catch that JSON response. Why it isn't returning in curl?" Are you asking me why the access token isn't being returned in your curl call?

Comment: Access token is returned but not this error when we hit the anove url with empty or invalid client id.

Comment: That will never happen. You have to authenticate in order to get an access token. That's the entire point of oauth. You authenticate, get an access token, and then send the token in future requests to show that you've authenticated. What are you not understanding about this?

Comment: How could I ever get access token with an invalid/blank client id? This would be stupid of me thinking that. I understand oauth very well. I just want to get the error which is returned when the above url is hit with invalid/blank client id. And that error is in JSON format, but I am not getting any response via curl.